# Java Chat Application

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a MultiClient Chat Application in which the chat is implemented in the client window. I've tried server and client code for the same.one clint to server is running good but teo client to server is not running properly one clint communication good but second one client not giving response.

**Client Code**

```
    package server1;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Clientchatform extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    static Socket conn;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField NewMsg;
    JTextArea ChatHistory;
    JButton Send;
String line;
BufferedReader br;
String response;
BufferedReader  is ;
PrintWriter os;
    public Clientchatform() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        panel = new JPanel();
        NewMsg = new JTextField();
        ChatHistory = new JTextArea();
        Send = new JButton("Send");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        ChatHistory.setBounds(20, 20, 450, 360);
        panel.add(ChatHistory);
        NewMsg.setBounds(20, 400, 340, 30);
        panel.add(NewMsg);
        Send.setBounds(375, 400, 95, 30);
        panel.add(Send);
        Send.addActionListener(this);
        conn = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2000);



        ChatHistory.setText("Connected to Server");
        this.setTitle("Client");
        while (true) {
            try {
                BufferedReader  is  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                                 br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String line = is.readLine();
                ChatHistory.setText(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n' + "Server:"
                        + line);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                ChatHistory.setText(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n'
                        + "Message sending fail:Network Error");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ((e.getSource() == Send) && (NewMsg.getText() != "")) {

            ChatHistory.setText(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n' + "Me:"
                    + NewMsg.getText());
            try {
                             br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                 PrintWriter os=new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                os.println(NewMsg.getText());
                                os.flush();

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                ChatHistory.append(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n'
                        + "Message sending fail:Network Error");

            }


            NewMsg.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        Clientchatform chatForm = new Clientchatform();
    }

}
```

**Server Code**

```
package server1;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class serverChatform  extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    static ServerSocket server;
    static Socket conn;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField NewMsg;
    JTextArea ChatHistory;
    JButton Send;
    //DataInputStream dis;
    //DataOutputStream dos;
        String line;
        BufferedReader  is ;
        public serverChatform() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        panel = new JPanel();
        NewMsg = new JTextField();
        ChatHistory = new JTextArea();
        Send = new JButton("Send");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        ChatHistory.setBounds(20, 20, 450, 360);
        panel.add(ChatHistory);
        NewMsg.setBounds(20, 400, 340, 30);
        panel.add(NewMsg);
        Send.setBounds(375, 400, 95, 30);
        panel.add(Send);
        this.setTitle("Server");
        Send.addActionListener(this);
        server = new ServerSocket(2000, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        ChatHistory.setText("Waiting for Client");
        conn = server.accept();
             //     ServerThread st=new ServerThread(conn);
               //   st.start();

        ChatHistory.setText(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n' + "Client Found");
        while (true) {
            try {
                BufferedReader  is  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                                  PrintWriter os=new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                 line=is.readLine();
                ChatHistory.append(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n' + "Client:"
                        + line);
            } catch (Exception e1)
                        {
                ChatHistory.setText(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n'
                        + "Message sending fail:Network Error");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }





    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ((e.getSource() == Send) && (NewMsg.getText() != "")) {
            ChatHistory.setText(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n' + "ME:"
                    + NewMsg.getText());
            try {
                 PrintWriter os =new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                        os.println(NewMsg.getText());
                                                os.flush();



            } catch (Exception e1) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            NewMsg.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
    IOException {
    new serverChatform();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track, but I've got a question for you to ask yourself.

```
    conn = server.accept();
         //     ServerThread st=new ServerThread(conn);
           //   st.start();

    ChatHistory.setText(ChatHistory.getText() + 'n' + "Client Found");
```

How often is this code executed? Consider that of course the main(),

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
IOException {
new serverChatform();
}
```

is only called once, and therefore only one serverChatform will ever be created.

As you seem to have written quite a bit of code yourself, and it therefore seems like you're ready to learn more, I'm not going to give a full solution, but merely a direction.

Once you accept a client, with `conn = server.accept();`, you will have to create another `new serverChatform();`. This has to happen in a different `Thread` though. How to do this, I leave as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Each connected client has to be served in its own thread. Additionally you need a Thread that continiously listens for new clients to connect. That would look like this.

```
List<Socket> clients; // Save the socket for each client
[...]
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Thread that runs forever listening for new clients
        while(true){
            Socket conn = server.accept();  
            // new client has connected, store its socket
            clients.add(conn);
            // and start new thread that interacts with this new client
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // SERVE CLIENT HERE!
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}).start();
```